# adding onclick event on replace with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, replace, onclick, replacewith

I'm having a problem on putting onclick event on a replaceWith on jquery. My function on the 2nd onclick event is not functioning. This is my sample code.

sample.html

```
<div id = "first_div" onClick = "replace()">First</div>
```

my.js

```
function replace() {
    $('#first_div').replaceWith("<div id = 'sec_div' onclick='flyout('fb')'>Second</div>");
}
```

When I click the first_div it works. It shows the 2nd_div, but when I click the 2nd div it doesn't do anything.

```
function flyout(data){
    if (data == "fb") $('#sec_div').replaceWith("<div>Last</div>");
}
```

Comment: Both answers below suggest the `.live()` function.  You may want to use the `.on()` function which has replaced `.live()` in more recent versions of jQuery.  http://api.jquery.com/on/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason your code doesn't work is that you're not passing a function to the 'onclick' of the `#sec_div` element. You have it defined as `onclick="flyout('fb');"`, but the flyout function doesn't return anything. I changed the code below so that `flyout` returns a function and encapsulates the value of `data` in its closure, in case you want to use this same function with different values for the `data` parameter.

Also, I have a provided a solution which helps to separate your HTML from your Javascript. Using jquery you can accomplish that by using the `delegate` method to bind a function to any event.

HTML:

```
<div id="first_div">First</div>
```

JS:

```
$("body").delegate('#first_div', 'click', replace);
$("body").delegate('#sec_div', 'click', flyout("fb"));

// change replace to:
function replace() {
    $(this).replaceWith("<div id='sec_div'>Second</div>");
}
// change flyout to:
function flyout(data){
    return (function(){ 
       if (data == "fb") {
          $(this).replaceWith("<div>Last</div>"); 
       }
    });
}
```

EDIT:
According to the latest jquery documentation use of the `live` method is deprecated, use `delegate` instead.

Comment: @ggreiner `.live()` function is not recommended. From the documention of jquery `.lve()` is superseded by `.delegate()` method.If using jQuery 1.7+ then `.on()` function is recommended.

Answer (score 1):

There is no click event bound to the new div.

Either add a new listener after the replaceWith() call or else use live() to listen at the document level.

Comment: Ha? what do you mean? I have click event on the sec_div and this is where the problem is. When clicking the sec_div, it doesn't show the Last div.

Comment: You put onclick in the code, but the DOM won't recognize it.  It's not bound to the new element.  Because the page is already built, you have to bind the new event with a different method.

Answer (score 1):

You haven't escaped it properly in the function replace. The

```
onclick='flyout('fb')'
```

part has three four single quotes. the second quote closes the first quote and the third quote starts a new string. Try escaping it as follows

```
  element="<div id = 'sec_div' onclick='flyout(\"fb\")'>Second</div>"
$('#first_div').replaceWith(element);
```

Also checkout http://jsfiddle.net/5Stuh/